# Setting Cursor.Position in Windows 10 not working

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I want to set the mouse cursor to a certain position by using:﻿﻿

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(Int32.Parse(X), Int32.Parse(Y));
```

This works normally in Windows 7, but not in Windows 10. The cursor is not moving, but when the position is on a button you can see the hover reaction.

Is this a known issue? If yes, is there a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1:**
This seems to be a visual problem meaning only the visible cursor does not move. For test purposes I have created a button (button_1) which performs above code on a click. I set the X and Y coordinates to be on another button (button_2). Now when I click button_1 button_2 gets highlighted as if the cursor is hovering on it. If I click button_1 again without moving the mouse, button_2 gets clicked. When I move the mouse between the clicks button_2 is not highlighted anymore. Thus, resulting in the second click doing the same as the first.

**EDIT 2**
I tried using the following function instead of `Cursor.Position`, but with the same result.

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
public static extern long SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

Comment: Sound like a Windows bug. I don't know, have use Win8.1

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is not a Windows 10 problem.
I did not realize that this issue could have something to do with the fact that I was working in a VM. Consider this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you need to execute the program as a system administrator if the external application also requires to run as a system administrator. Otherwise, Cursor doesn't work on the external application. This issue occurs in Windows 10 but not in Windows 7.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).